# Send Video from my Android app to WhatsApp

Tags: android, whatsapp

Using the following code I can send a text message from my app to WhatsApp. But unable to send photos and videos. Here is my code to send text messages.

```
private void openWhatsApp(){

        try {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+phone+"&text=" + Uri.parse("Text that you want to send to the current user")));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));

        }
        catch (Exception ignored){}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get file Uri then use it, try this

```
public void shareVideoWhatsApp() {
        Uri  uri;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=24)
        {
            uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",file);
        }
        else
        {
            uri=Uri.fromFile(file);
        }
       
        Intent videoshare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        videoshare.setType("*/*");
        videoshare.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        videoshare.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        videoshare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);

        startActivity(videoshare);

    }
```